# hello i am new to python. i installed matplotlib in my Visual studio but whenever i try to run the file it displays the error

Tags: matplotlib, graph, importerror

I wanted to plot a graph. but suddenly i could not because of the import error. yet i have installed matplotlib and numpy.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\user\Documents\plot.py", line 1, in 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 109, in 
from . import _api, _version, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in 
from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 56, in 
from matplotlib import _api, cbook, scale
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 23, in 
from matplotlib.ticker import (
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 136, in 
from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 46, in 
from matplotlib._path import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found.
PS C:\Users\user\Documents>

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
If you have already installed matplotlib, but the error still comes about. Then you have to download Microsoft C++ from their website.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145

install Microsoft c++ then you can try again to run your code.
it has worked for me like magic.
I got the solution from a youtube video.

link here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpwsvUkNAmg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).