# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

When I was trying to import matplotlib, I wrote

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

in my code.
and this error occured.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\aiProjects\opencv\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\blackhao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\blackhao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\blackhao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, _cm, cbook, scale
  File "C:\Users\blackhao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\scale.py", line 22, in <module>
    from matplotlib.ticker import (
  File "C:\Users\blackhao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\ticker.py", line 138, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "C:\Users\blackhao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 49, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _path: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried several ways such as reinstalling matplotlib and pasting new "Msvcp71.dll" and "Msvcr71.dll" files in my system folders. Anyways to solve this problem?

Comment: Try this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74334434/8786297

Answer (score 0):

... reinstall the matplotlib python package with this argument *--ignore-installed*:

```
pip3 install matplotlib --user --ignore-installed
```